# Error creating a pandas dataframe from a SQL query returning a numeric array

Tags: python, sql, pandas, postgresql, dataframe

A query to a PostgreSQL database returns a numeric array (300 components) and an integer for thousand of records.

```
cursor.execute(query)
records = cursor.fetchall()
X = pd.DataFrame([res[0] for res in records])
```

Then, a TypeError is rised on the last line:
"TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()"

The idea is to create a dataframe with the dataset resulting from the query, the array are the input variables to a Neural Network, and the integer value is a categorical variable as the output.

Comment: did you print `records`? I believe your issue is that it is equal to `None`

Answer (score 1):

My preferred way of doing this is using [pd.read_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html)

```
X = pd.read_sql(query, connection)
```

or, more commonly with sqlalchemy

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text
import pandas as pd

engine = create_engine('connection_string')
with engine.connect() as conn:
    X = pd.read_sql(text(query), conn)
```

SqlAlchemy typically handles all type issues for you.

In this scenario, I'm concerned the data isn't what you expect it is. I believe res[0] is actually an array/list for most rows, and *None* for some rows. That's how you reproduce this exact error. For my understanding res should be a tuple, and res[0] should be a specific value.

If indeed this is what you expect, the following should filter out the None rows.

```
cursor.execute(query)
records = cursor.fetchall()
X = pd.DataFrame([res[0] for res in records if res[0] is not None])
```

If you'd like to retain None rows, then the following change.

```
row_width = len(records[0][0])  # will fail if first record has None if first column, use a loop to find valid row in this case
X = pd.DataFrame([res[0] if res[0] is not None else [None] * row_width for res in records])
```

Comment: Yes, you are completely right, at the end I discovered the root of the problem , and this is in fact the presence of NULLs in the first column (the array of numeric). I have refactored the query to avoid the NULLs, and now it is working. Thank you very much.